# Bones don't respond to rigid body

Tags: armature, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I made a character with ragdoll physics, in which I made boxes with active rigid bodies, and parented them to the bones. Most bones react well, except for the right leg, which pulls away from the body when I play the animation.

[image]

[image]

How do I make sure it won't fly off?

I'm using this tutorial https://youtu.be/GaZAI8RIq0Q

**.blend file:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found your problem, there's a magic 90 degrees on one of your empty objects, if you reset to 0 it works like you wanted.

[image]

You can see the other empty that connects the other leg, doesn't have that 90 degrees on the X Axis.

Cheers,